# How to handle Double Click Event on cell of GridView

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have my View code as below. I want to add functionality like when I double click on any cell of DataGrid, it should reflect that value from the cell to Label Named as "Notification" Can you please let me know how to do it? As I am beginner, giving working example in my own code would help me more. Thanks.

**VehicalForm.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="Seris.VehicalForm"
            xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
            Title="MainWindow" Height="500" Width="600">
<Control>
    <Control.Template>
        <ControlTemplate>
            <WrapPanel Orientation="Vertical" Margin="10 " >
                <Label Content="Vehical No" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                <TextBox Name="VehicalNo_Text" Height="23" Width="80" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding VehicalNo}"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
                <Label Content="Model" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                <TextBox Name="Model_Text" Height="23" Width="80" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Model}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
                <Label Content="Manufacturing Date" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                <DatePicker Name="ManufacturingDate_DateTime" SelectedDate="{Binding ManufacturingDate, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                <Label Content="IU No" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                <TextBox Height="23" Width="80" Name="IUNO_Text" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding IUNo}" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                <Label Content="Personnel" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                <ComboBox Name="Personnel_Combo" Text="{Binding Personnel}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="116"/>
                <Separator Height="20" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Width="16"/>
                <Button Name="Save_Button" Command="{Binding SaveButton_Command}" Content="Save" Width="66"/>
                <Label x:Name="Error_Label" Content="{Binding ErrorMessage, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Foreground="Red" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="41" Width="137"/>
                <ListView Name ="Grid" Height="294" Width="371" >
                    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding ListItems, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" SelectionUnit="Cell" GridLinesVisibility="None" IsReadOnly="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" BorderThickness="0">
                        <DataGrid.Columns>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Vehical No" Binding="{Binding VehicalNo}" />
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Model" Binding="{Binding Model}" />
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="ManufacturingDate" Binding="{Binding ManufacturingDate}" />
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="IUNo" Binding="{Binding IUNo}" />
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Personnel" Binding="{Binding Personnel}" />
                        </DataGrid.Columns>
                    </DataGrid>
                </ListView>
                <Label Name="Notification"/>

            </WrapPanel>
            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsMouseOver, ElementName=Grid}" Value="true">
                    <Setter Property="Content" TargetName="Notification">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}Name is '{0}'}">
                                <Binding ElementName="Notification" Path="Text" />
                            </MultiBinding>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </DataTrigger>
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Control.Template>
</Control>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to manage double click on a cell of a datagrid, as explained here:
[How do i handle cell double click event on WPF DataGrid, equivalent to windows DataGrid's Events?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14557633/how-do-i-handle-cell-double-click-event-on-wpf-datagrid-equivalent-to-windows-d)

So, do not use your  but prefer another binding to update your notification label.

So in your xaml file you'll have something like:

```
<Label Name="Notification" Content="{Binding NotificationContent}"/>
```

And in your viewModel you will update the NotificationContent property when the command is triggered.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Your link is good but it doesn't follow MVVM structure. So not useful.

Comment: It could be acceptable to acces your viewModel as DataContext in your code behind. Or use another control than Datagrid and bind a command.