# Stop the cell to go into edit mode when it is double clicked

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface, datagrid

I have a DataGrid. I have Edit Button on each row of my DataGrid. When user clicks on this edit button every cell of that row goes into edit mode. When I click on any edit button it's template changes to save button. When I am done I click on that save button and DataGridRow comes out of the edit mode and Save Button again changes to Edit Button. This works fine.

Here is my code:

Xaml:

```
<DataGrid Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="3"  AutoGenerateColumns="False" RowHeaderWidth="0" GridLinesVisibility="Vertical"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource ItemsViewSource}}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}"
          CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserDeleteRows="False" CanUserReorderColumns="False"
          SelectionMode="Single" SelectionUnit="FullRow">

    <DataGrid.Columns>

        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Name of the Item" Width="*" SortDirection="Ascending">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderStyle>
                <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}}">
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left"/>
                </Style>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderStyle>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding Name, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" PreviewKeyDown="TextBox_PreviewKeyDown"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type DataGridCell}}">
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
                                <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                                    <ContentPresenter VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="5,0,0,0" />
                                </Grid>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellStyle>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>

        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Edit" Width="50" IsReadOnly="True">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Button Content="Edit" Style="{StaticResource EditSaveButton}"  
                            Command="{Binding DataContext.EditItemCommand, 
                                              RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Page}}}" 
                            Click="EditButton_Click"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>

        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Delete" Width="70" IsReadOnly="True">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Button Content="Delete" Style="{StaticResource DeleteButton}"
                            Command="{Binding DataContext.CancelItemEditOrDeleteCommand, 
                                              RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=Page}}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>

    </DataGrid.Columns>

</DataGrid>
```

code-behind(cs):

```
void EditButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    int colIndex = 0;
    int rowIndex = 0;

    DependencyObject dep = (DependencyObject)e.OriginalSource;
    while (dep != null && !(dep is DataGridCell))
    {
        dep = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(dep);
    }

    if (dep == null)
        return;
    DataGridRow row = null;
    if (dep is DataGridCell)
    {

        colIndex = ((DataGridCell)dep).Column.DisplayIndex;

        while (dep != null && !(dep is DataGridRow))
        {
            dep = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(dep);
        }

        row = (DataGridRow)dep;
        rowIndex = FindRowIndex(row);

    }

    while (dep != null && !(dep is DataGrid))
    {
        dep = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(dep);
    }

    if (dep == null)
        return;

    DataGrid dg = (DataGrid)dep;
    if (row != null)
    {
        var rows = GetDataGridRows(dg);

        if (row.IsEditing)
        {
            dg.CommitEdit(DataGridEditingUnit.Row, true);

            foreach (DataGridRow r in rows)
            {
                r.IsEnabled = true;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            dg.CurrentCell = new DataGridCellInfo(dg.Items[rowIndex], dg.Columns[0]);
            dg.BeginEdit();

            foreach (DataGridRow r in rows)
            {
                if (!(r.IsEditing))
                {
                    r.IsEnabled = false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

public DataGridCell GetDataGridCell(DataGridCellInfo cellInfo)
{
    var cellContent = cellInfo.Column.GetCellContent(cellInfo.Item);
    if (cellContent != null)
        return (DataGridCell)cellContent.Parent;

    return null;
}

private int FindRowIndex(DataGridRow row)
{
    DataGrid dataGrid = ItemsControl.ItemsControlFromItemContainer(row) as DataGrid;

    int index = dataGrid.ItemContainerGenerator.IndexFromContainer(row);

    return index;
}

public IEnumerable<DataGridRow> GetDataGridRows(DataGrid grid)
{
    var itemsSource = grid.ItemsSource as IEnumerable;
    if (null == itemsSource) yield return null;
    foreach (var item in itemsSource)
    {
        var row = grid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(item) as DataGridRow;
        if (null != row) yield return row;
    }
}
```

Basically I have 2 questions here:

1. When I DoubleClick a cell, that cell goes into edit mode. I want to stop that behavior as I am providing the edit button.
2. Once any row goes to edit mode, and if I change data in 1st cell of that row and now if I move to the next cell, the 1st cell changes its template to cellTemplate. I don't want to change its template. I mean I want it to remain in it's cellEditTemplate upto the time when I click on Edit Button again.

If anybody has an answer to any one of the question, then also please post.

Thanks.

Comment: Number of the beast is tempting me not to upvote

Comment: @CarbineCoder I can't understand, what you are trying to say?

Comment: you will get 666 only once and now its gone

Comment: @CarbineCoder Thanks for mentioning that. But I really don't look at those points.

Comment: Christian background needed to understand the joke.

Comment: @Fratyx Come-on I am a person who don't believe in religions. I believe in humans.

Comment: @Fratyx now its pointless to explain him the joke, he is not a believer what a shame :(

Comment: @CarbineCoder i believe that god lives in each humans soul and not in any religion.

Comment: But religion is always good for laugh.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your second question to make the cell editable always when clicked the Edit button you can simply have the Cell template as Textbox instead of a textblock and make it readonly in case of normal scenario when the row is editable make the textbox editable this way it will remain in edit mode even when you move to next cell. This will also solve your first problem of cell going in edit mode for double click as the textbox is readonly until user presses the Edit button the double click effect will not work for him so the cell will not go in edit mode.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I didn't notice your answer. I would like to ask you 1 thing. As you say that I should use TextBox as cellTemplate, But I want to show Label or TextBlock as cellTemplate because TextBox visible all the time looks very ugly.

Comment: If you will have Textbox as cell template then you will not face the problem of having extra EditCellTemplate. also it will help as I already said making it readonly default will disable the double click effect on Cell. and you can handle the Editable or Readonly behavior on your own.

Comment: I would like to ask you one more question: If I have same scenario but cellTemplate is TextBlock and cellEditTemplate is ComboBox, then how would you deal with the problem?

Answer (score 2):

Just try something like

```
void Cell_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e){
(...)
e.Handled;
}
```

as this will prevent further event callback.

Also this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14557633/how-do-i-handle-cell-double-click-event-on-wpf-datagrid-equivalent-to-windows-d) might be helpful.